# PHP: get the highest and lowest value in a mysql column?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the highest and lowest value in a mysql column but I hav eno idea if this is even possible!

I came across this code in the official MYSQL forum but I really don't know how to get those values as PHP variables!

```
SELECT
(SELECT `price` FROM mytable ORDER BY `price` LIMIT 1) AS lowest,
(SELECT `price` FROM mytable ORDER BY `price` DESC LIMIT 1) AS highest
```

so basically what i need to do is to create PHP variables from that mysql quesry and to just get the highest value as `$hiestprice` and the lowest as `$lowestprice`

so i went ahead and I did:

```
$sql = "SELECT
    (SELECT `price` FROM mytable ORDER BY `price` LIMIT 1) AS lowest,
    (SELECT `price` FROM mytable ORDER BY `price` DESC LIMIT 1) AS highest";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query ); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

$hiestprice = $row['price'];
$lowestprice = $row['price'];

}

}
```

But that is wrong and I get nothing returned on my PHP page when I echo the `$hiestprice` and `$lowestprice`!

Could someone please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: If you `var_dump($row);` you will see, you need to access them via `$row['lowest']` and `$row['highest']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first you could optimize the query and use

```
SELECT MIN(  `price` ) AS  `lowest` , MAX(  `price` ) AS  `highest` FROM  `mytable`
```

Than you could use the prices with

```
$highestprice = $row['highest'];
$lowestprice = $row['lowest']
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `AS lowest` suffix, in php and other clients (like phpmyadmin) you will get this alias `lowest`.

You can optimize your query to one select:

```
SELECT MIN(`price`) AS `lowest`, MAX(`price`) AS `highest` FROM `mytable`;
```

and in php (for both queries, your and optimized) you should get by alias:

```
<?php

$hiestprice = $row['lowest'];
$lowestprice = $row['highest'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$hiestprice = $row['highest'];
$lowestprice = $row['lowest'];
```

Try this.

You should consider editing query as well,

```
SELECT MIN(`price`) AS lowest , MAX(`price`) AS highest FROM  `mytable`
```

Hope this helps.