# PHP MariaDB PDO count duplicate values

Tags: php, pdo, count, duplicates, mariadb

Maybe a stupid question, but I can't find anything on it. I know you can do counts and some basic math with queries.

Is there a way to make the database count and return results with the highest or lowest number of occurrences?

Lets say you had all the pages of a library in a database and you wanted to know the top 5 characters used or maybe the least used.

I guess the easiest example would be the lottery. Lets say you had a table of past lottery results. Lets say you wanted to return a list of the top 10 most drawn numbers. Lets say the numbers can range from 1 to 100.

It wouldn't be very efficient to run the following query 100 different times and then run some php to sort the data.

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE ball=1
```

Surely there must be a way to return a count of the most duplicated data.

Perhaps I am over thinking this. Anyway, thanks for any help in the matter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708444/php-get-the-highest-and-lowest-value-in-a-mysql-column

Comment: `GROUP BY` is a wonderful tool for tasks such as this.

Comment: "I know you can do counts and some basic math with queries." I would suggest looking into what you can do with SQL more. There's SO MUCH more you can achieve than some maths. The better you are at SQL the less you have to program and you can gain some unmatched application speeds by utilising the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called grouping, the `group by` clause will let you do that, make sure you don't just pull out the count but also the thing you're counting, in this case `ball`.

Get the lowest number occurrences:

```
SELECT ball, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY ball ORDER BY ball ASC limit 1;
```

Get the highest number occurrences:

```
SELECT ball, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY ball ORDER BY ball DESC limit 1;
```

If you want them all in one result you can use a union/union all:

```
(SELECT ball, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY ball ORDER BY ball ASC limit 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ball, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY ball ORDER BY ball DESC limit 1);
```

Comment: Perhaps mention ordering by the actual count

Comment: *Is there a way to make the database count and return results with the **highest** or **lowest** number of occurrences?*

Comment: Sorry, hit submit way too soon!

Comment: Thank you, that's great! Would you use `UNION` to compare and process multiple columns? Say there was a ball1, ball2, ball3 each have the potential to have the same data stored.

Comment: @Sabyre no, each subquery always returns one result only, so using the union just allows you to show 2 results, the highest occurrence and the lowest occurrence. If you had 2 items that had the same number of highest or lowest occurrences then the DB would just pick the first one it finds because of the LIMIT.

Comment: Let's say the field data was txt or varchar and the numbers were something like `4 23 46 57 81` or `4-23-46-57-81` How could you count and eliminate the delimiters?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use

```
SELECT column, COUNT(*) 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY column_name
```

this will count all of the existing entries for the specific column_name
you should use column before `COUNT(*)` so you know what has that many values.

i hope this helps!